# xmltodict - no element line 1 column 0

Tags: python, ubuntu, xmltodict

I am receiving this error in python 2.7 and 3.5 on ubuntu that expat cannot read the first element.

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Line 1 looks quite normal for and has parsed before.

```
<meeting id="42736" barriertrial="0" venue="Rosehill Gardens" date="2016-03-19T00:00:00" gearchanges="-1" stewardsreport="-1" gearlist="-1" racebook="0" postracestewards="0" meetingtype="TAB" rail="Timing - Electronic : Rail - +2m" weather="Fine      " trackcondition="Good" nomsdeadline="2016-03-14T11:00:00" weightsdeadline="2016-03-15T16:00:00" acceptdeadline="2016-03-16T09:00:00" jockeydeadline="2016-03-16T12:00:00">
  <club abbrevname="Australian Turf Club" code="56398" associationclass="1" website="http://" />
  <race id="213262" number="1" nomnumber="7" division="0" name="NATHAN'S FAMOUS EPONA STAKES" mediumname="EPONA" shortname="EPONA STAKES" stage="Results" distance="1900" minweight="0" raisedweight="0" class="~         " age="3U        " grade="0" weightcondition="SWP       " trophy="1000" owner="1000" trainer="0" jockey="0" strapper="0" totalprize="150000" first="90000" second="30000" third="15000" fourth="7500" fifth="3000" time="2016-03-19T12:40:00" bonustype="          " nomsfee="0" acceptfee="0" trackcondition="Good      " timingmethod="Electronic" fastesttime="1-56.83   " sectionaltime="600/35.3  " formavailable="0" racebookprize="Of $150000 and trophies of $1000. First $90000 and trophies of $1000 to owner, second $30000, third $15000, fourth $7500, fifth $3000, sixth $1500, seventh $1500, eighth $1500">
    <condition line="1">Of $150000 and trophies of $1000. First $90000 and trophies of $1000 to owner, second $30000, third $15000, fourth $7500, fifth $3000, sixth $1500, seventh $1500, eighth $1500</condition>
    <condition line="3">No class restriction, Set Weights plus Penalties, For Three-Years-Old and Upwards, Fillies and Mares, (Group 3)</condition>
    <condition line="5">No Allowances for apprentices. Field Limit: 14 + 4 EM</condition>
    <nomination number="4" saddlecloth="4" horse="Vergara" id="171115" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="1" trainernumber="38701" trainersurname="Cummings" trainerfirstname="Anthony" trainertrack="Randwick" rsbtrainername="Anthony Cummings" jockeynumber="86876" jockeysurname="McDonald" jockeyfirstname="James" barrier="7" weight="55" rating="93" description="B M 5 Snippetson x Graces Spirit (Flying Spur)" colours="Yellow, Red Epaulettes And Cap" owners="Anthony Cummings Thoroughbreds Pty Ltd Syndicate (Mgrs: A &amp; B Cummings) &amp; P C Racing Investments Syndicate (Mgr: P J Carroll)  " dob="2010-10-07T00:00:00" age="6" sex="M" career="30-7-4-2 $295445.00" thistrack="6-1-1-0 $90500.00" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="17-3-2-2 $101440.00" heavytrack="5-0-1-0 $20200.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="7-2-1-2 $108340.00" secondup="7-1-1-0 $43200.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="1" weightvariation="0" variedweight="55" decimalmargin="0.00" penalty="0" pricestarting="$12" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Heavens Above" id="187674" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="736" trainersurname="Martin" trainerfirstname="Tim" trainertrack="Rosehill" rsbtrainername="Tim Martin" jockeynumber="46930" jockeysurname="Angland" jockeyfirstname="Tye" barrier="6" weight="56" rating="88" description="B M 4 Street Cry(IRE) x Reggie(NZ) (Germano(GB))" colours="Yellow, Green Chevrons, Striped Cap" owners="President Bloodstock Pty Ltd (Mgr: R C Kemister)" dob="2011-08-12T00:00:00" age="5" sex="M" career="12-3-3-4 $271520.00" thistrack="4-0-3-0 $41425.00" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="10-2-2-4 $214845.00" heavytrack="0-0-0-0" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="2-0-1-1 $20710.00" secondup="2-0-2-0 $24675.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="2" weightvariation="0" variedweight="56" decimalmargin="0.20" penalty="0" pricestarting="$3.80F" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="6" saddlecloth="6" horse="Sweet Fire" id="184732" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="681" trainersurname="Waller" trainerfirstname="Chris" trainertrack="Rosehill" rsbtrainername="Chris Waller" jockeynumber="51661" jockeysurname="Berry" jockeyfirstname="Tommy" barrier="5" weight="54" rating="85" description="BR M 4 Shamardal(USA) x Zarinia(IRE) (Intikhab(USA))" colours="Lilac And White Halves, Black Cap" owners="E J Lucas " dob="2011-09-25T00:00:00" age="5" sex="M" career="15-4-2-2 $212750.00" thistrack="6-1-1-1 $56690.00" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="9-2-1-2 $120395.00" heavytrack="1-0-0-0 $450.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="3-0-0-0 $1900.00" secondup="3-1-1-0 $42200.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="3" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="0.50" penalty="0" pricestarting="$7" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="7" saddlecloth="7" horse="Alegria" id="181928" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="1" trainernumber="235" trainersurname="O'Shea" trainerfirstname="John" trainertrack="Agnes Banks/Hawkesbury" rsbtrainername="John O'Shea" jockeynumber="40275" jockeysurname="Clark" jockeyfirstname="Tim" barrier="1" weight="54" rating="81" description="B M 4 Medaglia D'oro(USA) x Pure Joy (Fusaichi Pegasus(USA))" colours="Royal Blue" owners="Godolphin" dob="2011-10-06T00:00:00" age="5" sex="M" career="12-3-1-5 $216850.00" thistrack="4-1-0-2 $89600.00" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="5-1-1-3 $87575.00" heavytrack="4-2-0-1 $114275.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="3-2-0-1 $80500.00" secondup="3-0-0-2 $20850.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="4" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="0.70" penalty="0" pricestarting="$8.50" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="11" saddlecloth="11" horse="Piamimi" id="158914" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="773" trainersurname="Bennett" trainerfirstname="Greg" trainertrack="Scone" rsbtrainername="Greg Bennett" jockeynumber="48503" jockeysurname="Williams" jockeyfirstname="Craig" barrier="8" weight="54" rating="75" description="B OR BR M 6 Not a Single Doubt x Blurrta(NZ) (Bahhare(USA))" colours="Yellow, Dark Blue Diamonds, Striped Sleeves And Cap" owners="Dr M Wylie, K Kenny, J Canning, M Mcfayden, B Hyde &amp; P Toubji " dob="2009-08-23T00:00:00" age="7" sex="M" career="35-6-4-3 $170275.00" thistrack="2-0-0-0 $5150.00" thisdistance="2-0-0-0 $900.00" goodtrack="25-3-2-2 $78640.00" heavytrack="4-1-1-1 $24510.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="8-1-3-0 $27375.00" secondup="8-1-0-2 $32645.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="5" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="1.10" penalty="0" pricestarting="$41" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="10" saddlecloth="10" horse="Blendwell" id="171408" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="78024" trainersurname="Moody" trainerfirstname="Peter G" trainertrack="Warwick Farm" rsbtrainername="Peter G Moody" jockeynumber="85036" jockeysurname="Lane" jockeyfirstname="Damian" barrier="10" weight="54" rating="78" description="B M 5 Hard Spun(USA) x Bridie Belle(NZ) (Al Akbar)" colours="Tartan, Red Sash And Armbands" owners="D &amp; M Esplin Pty Ltd (Mgr: Mrs M E Esplin)" dob="2010-10-06T00:00:00" age="6" sex="M" career="17-4-3-4 $107845.00" thistrack="0-0-0-0" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="8-0-1-2 $25135.00" heavytrack="2-2-0-0 $42000.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="6-0-0-3 $8835.00" secondup="3-1-0-1 $20050.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="6" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="1.20" penalty="0" pricestarting="$17" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="3" saddlecloth="3" horse="Adorabeel (NZ)" id="166836" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="1942" trainersurname="Pride" trainerfirstname="Joseph" trainertrack="Warwick Farm" rsbtrainername="Joseph Pride" jockeynumber="86280" jockeysurname="Clipperton" jockeyfirstname="Sam" barrier="9" weight="56" rating="86" description="BR OR BLK M 6 Savabeel x Plaza Doree(FR) (Saumarez(GB))" colours="Maroon, White Crossed Sashes, Yellow Armbands And Cap" owners="Mystery Downs (Mgr: F W Cook)" dob="2009-09-11T00:00:00" age="7" sex="M" career="34-6-5-4 $281810.00" thistrack="11-1-2-1 $105750.00" thisdistance="2-0-0-0 $3800.00" goodtrack="24-3-3-1 $203910.00" heavytrack="0-0-0-0" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="7-1-1-1 $28650.00" secondup="7-0-2-1 $25050.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="7" weightvariation="0" variedweight="56" decimalmargin="2.30" penalty="0" pricestarting="$13" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="8" saddlecloth="8" horse="Mary Lou" id="172933" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="1" trainernumber="38701" trainersurname="Cummings" trainerfirstname="Anthony" trainertrack="Randwick" rsbtrainername="Anthony Cummings" jockeynumber="86596" jockeysurname="Collett" jockeyfirstname="Jason" barrier="11" weight="54" rating="80" description="B M 5 Fastnet Rock x Miss Alabama(NZ) (Woodman(USA))" colours="Red, Black Diagonal Stripes And Armbands, Quartered Cap" owners="E-Thoroughbred (Mgr: A W &amp; M G Bott) &amp; Evergreen Rich (Mgr: A W Bott, P K Siu, M Siu &amp; E Siu)" dob="2010-09-18T00:00:00" age="6" sex="M" career="18-3-3-4 $156860.00" thistrack="3-1-0-1 $33375.00" thisdistance="1-1-0-0 $17250.00" goodtrack="14-3-2-4 $130335.00" heavytrack="2-0-0-0 $525.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="3-1-0-0 $31125.00" secondup="3-0-1-2 $25100.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="8" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="2.70" penalty="0" pricestarting="$18" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="9" saddlecloth="9" horse="Skyline Blush" id="182533" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="1" trainernumber="38701" trainersurname="Cummings" trainerfirstname="Anthony" trainertrack="Randwick" rsbtrainername="Anthony Cummings" jockeynumber="1472" jockeysurname="McEvoy" jockeyfirstname="Kerrin" barrier="4" weight="54" rating="80" description="B M 4 Northern Meteor x Cara Y Cruz(USA) (King of Kings(IRE))" colours="Red, Black Stripes" owners="Gooree Stud (E M Cojuangco &amp; M C Cummings)" dob="2011-10-29T00:00:00" age="5" sex="M" career="14-5-0-2 $204190.00" thistrack="4-1-0-1 $52225.00" thisdistance="2-1-0-1 $41375.00" goodtrack="7-0-0-1 $19535.00" heavytrack="4-2-0-1 $111125.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="3-1-0-0 $21125.00" secondup="3-0-0-1 $12460.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="9" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="3.10" penalty="0" pricestarting="$9.50" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="5" saddlecloth="5" horse="All Cerise" id="171801" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="0" trainernumber="681" trainersurname="Waller" trainerfirstname="Chris" trainertrack="Rosehill" rsbtrainername="Chris Waller" jockeynumber="86721" jockeysurname="Dunn" jockeyfirstname="Dwayne" barrier="3" weight="54" rating="92" description="B M 5 Redoute's Choice x Trick Taker(USA) (Capote(USA))" colours="Purple, White Hoops, Black Seams, Purple And White Quartered Cap" owners="Woppitt Bloodstock (Mgr: Mrs D N Kepitis)" dob="2010-11-05T00:00:00" age="6" sex="M" career="28-6-3-3 $349890.00" thistrack="10-1-1-1 $111750.00" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="21-6-2-3 $327690.00" heavytrack="2-0-0-0 $450.00" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="7-1-0-2 $45790.00" secondup="4-1-0-0 $71200.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="10" weightvariation="0" variedweight="54" decimalmargin="4.10" penalty="0" pricestarting="$6" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Gust of Wind (NZ)" id="181079" idnumber="" regnumber="" blinkers="1" trainernumber="41655" trainersurname="Sargent" trainerfirstname="John" trainertrack="Randwick" rsbtrainername="John Sargent" jockeynumber="84015" jockeysurname="Avdulla" jockeyfirstname="Brenton" barrier="2" weight="59" rating="106" description="B M 4 Darci Brahma(NZ) x Starrystarrynight(IRE) (Sadler's Wells(USA))" colours="Yellow, White Checked Sash, Checked Sleeves And Cap" owners="Go Bloodstock (Mgr: Sir O G Glenn)" dob="2011-09-07T00:00:00" age="5" sex="M" career="12-3-0-0 $974900.00" thistrack="0-0-0-0" thisdistance="0-0-0-0" goodtrack="10-2-0-0 $279150.00" heavytrack="0-0-0-0" slowtrack="" deadtrack="" fasttrack="0-0-0-0" firstup="4-1-0-0 $8900.00" secondup="3-1-0-0 $20250.00" mindistancewin="0" maxdistancewin="0" finished="11" weightvariation="0" variedweight="59" decimalmargin="7.40" penalty="0" pricestarting="$15" sectional200="0" sectional400="0" sectional600="0" sectional800="0" sectional1200="0" bonusindicator="" />
  </race>
</meeting>
```

and my script is

```
import xmltodict

'''import csv
import re
from sys import argv
SCRIPT, FILENAME = argv


def out_file_name(file_name):
    """take an input file and keep the name with appended _clean"""
    file_parts = file_name.split(".",)
    output_file = file_parts[0] + '_clean.' + file_parts[1]
    return output_file'''

with open('20160319RHIL0_edit.xml', 'r+') as f:
    my = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
    eventID = my['meeting']["@id"]
    location = my['meeting']["@venue"]
    eventDate = my['meeting']["@date"]
    meeting = [eventID, location, eventDate]
    raceFields = []
    for race in my['meeting']['race']:
        raceArr = []
        # race.append(race["@id"],race["@number"])
        raceNum = race["@number"]
        raceID = race["@id"]
        # print(race["@id"] + '\t' + race["@number"])
        for noms in race['nomination']:
            saddle = noms["@number"]
            horse = noms["@horse"]
            horseId = noms["@id"]
            barrier = noms["@barrier"]
            career = noms["@career"]
            rating = noms["@rating"]
            sexA = noms["@sex"]
            # trackRec = noms["@thistrack"]
            age = noms["@age"]
            description = noms["@description"]
            # price = noms["@pricestarting"]
            weights = noms["@weight"]
            # print(saddle + '\t' + horse + '\t' + horseId)

            myArr = [eventID, location, eventDate, raceNum, raceID, saddle,
                     horse, horseId, barrier, career, age, description, weights]
            raceFields.append(myArr)


print(raceFields)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem..are you sure your file actually starts with `<meeting`?

Comment: @alecxe         yes. It does not sure though why it worked on windows on anaconda and fsiled on command line ununtu. Made sure i got latest from my git but no go. Same test file in git too.

Comment: @Rad Lexus     i read that post before posting but libraries and resolution do not relate.

Comment: Well, it did produce that exact error. So then I can only agree with @alecxe: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: @Rad Lexus     so you get that error as well, what OS?

Comment: That would be Mac OSX. Tinkering with the XML file itself showed other errors; parsing the same file twice was the only way to get your "no element found: line 1, column **0**". Grasping for straws: you commented out part of the code. So are you positively sure that **the exact code as posted here** fails, with that error?

Comment: Its all in xmlconv folder on my git should be same https://github.com/MortalCatalyst/xmlrace

Comment: I finally got the same error when using your code and data from the git source. The reason is `20160409RAND0.xml` is an empty file.